# Как вызвать и проверить Get запрос в ASP .Net Core Web Api?

Tags: c#, mysql, api, asp, core

[image: Не находит этот запрос][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос в следующем : Создал я веб апи для ,того чтобы работать в андроиде с ним. Загрузил модели из БД MySql .Создал контролер для продукта ,на фото он изображен.Как мне проверить работоспособность моих методов GET ,если я запускаю приложение и особо ничего не поменялось
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну так откройте в браузере нужные ссылки и проверяйте. В чем проблема я что-то не пойму? Не знаете по какой ссылке? Ну они вон у вас в виде комментариев указаны. Или не знаете как в адресную строку это написать?)

Comment: А  как открыть я пробывал набирать http://localhost:41592/Products/index.html и ничего нет не удалось найти страницу

Comment: От куда вы взяли `index.html`, это API ведь. Посмотрите внимательней на комментарии у каждого метода API, там все показано.

Comment: Я не знаю как вызвать этот метод GET Product

Comment: index.html создался ,когда я создал контроллер ProductsController

Comment: Еще раз повторю - читайте комментарии у своего кода, вы там видите `index.html`? Я нет. У вас простые API методы, значит просто их и вызывайте как `site/products` - получение всех продуктов, `site/products/details/5` - получить конкретный продукт, где 5 - это id, ну и так далее. То есть, у вас идет `[сайт]/названиеКонтроллера/НазваниеМетода/ПараметрыМетода`.

Comment: Понял ,спасибо.А сайт это урл локалхоста?

Comment: http://localhost:41592/swagger/Products/Details/5 Я пытаюсь вот так ввести ,но пишет что нет такой страницы

Comment: У меня хоть просто вводи после localhost:41592/Products ничего нет ,кроме того что нет такой страницы

Comment: у вас порт правильный? В студии нажмите F5, приложение запускается? По идее у вас должен открыться браузер, когда вы F5 нажимаете. В браузере уже ищите ваши API, подозреваю где то в /products или в /api/products

Comment: Что запускается добавил в фото

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте перед `public class ProductsController : Controller`

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
```

И для методов вызова так же укажите атрибуты `[HttpGet]`

И насколько помниться в MVC контроллер должен наследоваться от `ControllerBase`

Объясняю :
В данный момент сваггер никак не может заиндексировать контроллер, а так же у него не указаны аттрибуты эндпоинтов.
Для этого необходимо указать что это ApiController и его путь

Та же ситуация и для методов, указать тип запроса через атрибут `[Http%type%]`

После этого эндпоинт отобразиться в Swagger'e